# what should be the relation ship between both the tables so each student can have separate marksid

Tags: sql

i am new to sql
I have 2 tables first one with marks and second one with students.
marks have a primary key of marksid and students have primary key student id.
I want to know what should be the relation ship between both the tables so each student can have separate  marksid.
and what will be the sql query to get their data.

I have tried one to one relationship with this select query
 s="select  s.Student Name,z.Hourly1Marks  from Student s,marks z "
but it is showing Cartesian product of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Study the concept of INNER JOIN (if each student has one mark, i.e. 1:1 relationship), and LEFT JOIN (if each student can have multiple marks, i.e. 1:n relationship).

You used an inner join without a restriction. What you need is something like

```
SELECT S.name, Z.marks
FROM students S
  JOIN marks Z ON S.student_id = Z.student_id
```

or equivalently

```
SELECT S.name, Z.marks
FROM students S, marks Z
WHERE S.student_id = Z.student_id
```

for a 1:1 relationship case, or

```
SELECT S.name, Z.marks
FROM students S
  LEFT JOIN marks Z ON S.student_id = Z.student_id
```

for a 1:N relationship case.

Comment: Inner joins cover 1:N relationships as well.  The only time a left (outer) join is useful is when you have null or non-matching values on your join columns, which I'm not certain is applicable to his question.  You also don't make this distinction clear in your answer.

Comment: @TimPote: When one says 1:N, it is usually considered that `N >= 0`, since those kinds of relationship vastly outnumber the ones where `N > 0`, which makes the situations where an inner join is applicable to 1:N relations exceptions to a rule. If it's possible for a student to have several marks, then it is most likely also possible that he won't have any - and inner join fails.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have two tables:

```
Students
--------------
IDStudent
Name
....

Marks
--------------
IDMarks
Hourly1Marks
```

and the relation between Studend and Marks is 'A student could have 0 or more Marks' then you need to add a column in the table Marks - call it `studentID` and this column is used as foreign key for the student table.

then you can write this query

```
select s.Name, z.Hourly1Marks 
from Student s left join marks z 
    on z.studentID = s.IDStudent
```

that will give you back all students and their marks (also the student without any marks)
or, if you want only the students with at least one mark

```
select s.Name, z.Hourly1Marks 
from Student s inner join marks z 
    on z.studentID = s.IDStudent
```